# How to setup geopermissions for beta number?

Tags: twilio

I have bought a Hungarian number (which is still in beta) and I try to make an outbound voice call to other number in Hungary.

But I get
*Account not authorized to call +36#########. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: [https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international_)*

The beta countries are not listed on geopermissions page in control panel. How could I setup the permission?

Comment: Are you saying you can't find Hungary in your international geopermissions?

Comment: @philnash yes, exactly

Comment: That seems like a bug or issue with your account as I can see Hungary in that list. Can you send your Account SID and details of this to the [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) team and see what they can find out.